# Codeblocks GTK project not found gtk.h and this path not contain include or lib folder

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, codeblocks, gtk3

what is the true path to prevent codeblocks error.[image]

I know question very short but when I selected any path I am getting error

Comment: Do you find `gtk.h` somewhere on your harddrive?

Comment: @Gerhardh, yes I found path that contains gtk.h file: `D:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk` but when I selected this path I am getting error: http://imgur.com/t9K38L4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Create New console C project

2-Right Click your project and click properties in the context menu

3-go to the libraries page

4-click 'Avaliable in pkg-config' in the known libraries layout

5-and make it like the following picture[image]